# Preserving numeric values in appengine endpoints json

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

so I have a `User` entity that is defined as follows:

```
public class User {
  @Id @Setter @SerializedName (ID) @ApiResourceProperty (name = ID)
  protected         String       id;

  @Index @Setter @SerializedName (EMAIL) @ApiResourceProperty (name = EMAIL)
  protected         String       email;

  @Setter @SerializedName (DISPLAY_NAME) @ApiResourceProperty (name = DISPLAY_NAME)
  protected         String       displayName;

  @SerializedName (CREATED) @ApiResourceProperty (name = CREATED)
  protected         long         created;

  @Setter @SerializedName (MODIFIED) @ApiResourceProperty (name = MODIFIED) 
  protected long         modified;

  @ApiResourceProperty (name = ACCOUNT_STATE) @SerializedName (ACCOUNT_STATE)
  protected         AccountState accountState;
```

}

When an instance of this `User` object is serialized, I get a JSON like below

```
{
  "id" : "a1234",
  "em" : "bob@bobmail.com",
  "dn" : "Bob DeBuildeur",
  "ct" : "1402635502580",
  "mt" : "1402635502580",
  "as" : "UNVERIFIED"
}
```

The ***as*** value above is an enum that I'd like to serialize as *-1*, *0*, or *1*.

The ***ct*** and ***mt*** values are timestamps and I'd like them as `long`s.

So I'd like to see this JSON instead:

```
{
  "id" : "a1234",
  "em" : "bob@bobmail.com",
  "dn" : "Bob DeBuildeur",
  "ct" : 1402635502580,
  "mt" : 1402635502580,
  "as" : -1
}
```

Where/how do I take over the serialization of this object to *properly* serialize it to JSON?

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of client library generation, you have to change the type of "as" to an int, if you want to serialize it as one. You can use @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE) to ignore the actual "as" field, and then use @ApiResourceProperty(name = "as") on an int field or accessor/mutator to serialize "as" as an integer.

As for longs, they are always serialized as strings, because JavaScript can't handle the full range of a long in a double. There is unfortunately no good workaround here, but if you use a client library, it will automatically convert them to a numeric type in the client language.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the enum type by using following annotation and create another set of getter and setter methods that return handle the int value of the same enum field

@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)